# 100% height on css table

Tags: html, css, height, css-tables

I am trying to make a fluid layout that has no fixed height or width elements. The body of my page is divided into three columns (and since I want them all to be equal heights, I've decided to use css tables). However, when I try and add a 100% height property to the table div (or the table-cell divs) they don't expand to the full size of div.middle. I have made a JS fiddle for this question with the full code http://jsfiddle.net/3NMw5/, but here is a snippet:

```
<body>
    <div class='titleBar'>
        <div class='wrap'>
            <img src='../images/logo.png' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='middle'>
        <div class='wrap mainContent'>
                <div class='leftColumn'>left here</div>
                <div class='center'>center</div>
                <div class='rightColumn'>right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footerBar'><div class='wrap'>footer</div></div>
</body>
```

and the css:

```
div.mainContent { display: table; height: 100%;}
div.leftColumn { width: 20%; display: table-cell; background-color: #D2B48C; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
div.rightColumn {width: 20%; display: table-cell;}
div.center {width: 60%; display: table-cell;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `height: 200px;` to mainContent.

```
div.mainContent {
display: table;
height: 200px;
}
```

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NMw5/5/) for the code.

Adding `height: 100%;` should also work.

Your problem was not that the columns were not stretching to full height, but rather that mainContent was not fully stretching.

--

EDIT: Okay, so the *real* problem comes when you try and make your container that fluid, because height is harder for a browser to calculate than width.

> The problem occurs when you set a percentage height on an element who's parent elements don't have heights set. In other words, the parent elements have a default height: auto;. You are, in effect, asking the browser to calculate a height from an undefined value. Since that would equal a null-value, the result is that the browser does nothing.

In order to define the height of the div to a relative height, you must set the height of the parent elements as well.

By adding `height: 100%` to `.middle`, you get something close to what you are after. [See the jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3NMw5/13/).

Read more about the height issue [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately, height: 100% doesn't work (it collapses to the height of text) and I don't want to use a fixed height (px's) because I want the design to dynamically size itself based on the screen size.

Comment: Yes, it does work? http://jsfiddle.net/3NMw5/9/ - add height 100% to mainContent.

Comment: Yours worked because you had static height properties on the divs. Check out this fiddle, it is what I am trying to accomplish, only I want to replace min-height: 300px with a fluid height property. http://jsfiddle.net/3NMw5/10/

Comment: I'm not seeing the min-height: 300px you are talking about in that fiddle.

Comment: div.leftColumn {width: 20%; height: 300px;
Near the bottom of the css

Comment: This would work perfect, except that I want my .middle to expand as content increases. If I define the height property, (i.e. height = 70% instead of min-height=70%) then if I get a large amount of content, it won't expand.

Comment: I am somewhat out of options than :) You could make them all position absolute and use javascript/jQuery to set the height/position of the footer :)

Comment: I was thinking about using jquery to do it, but I wanted to find a more organic method if possible. Thanks for all your help, excellent suggestions.

Comment: Good luck to you! Let me know how it goes.